# How to exclude a button on textbox validation in vb.net 2012?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to visualstudio .net. I have a form with a 7 textbox, one Cancel and submit button on it. I do handle textbox.validating every textbox, and I have the form setup so the Cancel button is the Cancel button. Anybody knows how to exclude the cancel button during the textbox validation?

```
Private Sub txtFname_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtFname.Validating
    If txtFname.Text = "" Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtFname, "Text cannot be empty")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub txtFname_Validated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtFname.Validated
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtFname, "")
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude the cancel button"?

Comment: I mean the cancel button is not functional when textbox begins to validate the user input. The problem is, the user can't cancel his/her actions.

Comment: I think you have the question backwards. Do you actually mean that you don't want to perform the validation when the Cancel button is clicked?  If so then you have to set the `CausesValidation` property of the button to `False`.  The documentation for the `Validating` event mentions that so you should already have known.